# Making link names shorter in pdoc3 automated html documentation

Tags: python-3.x, docstring, pdoc

I am generating html documentation via docstring and pdoc3 for the first time.

I would like to replace displayed names of qualified internal and external links, as I have seen for example in the pdoc3 documentation itself as such

`` A special type of documentation object `pdoc.External` is used to... ``

result in this text, where "External" is a link.

"A special type of documentation object External is used to..."

When I do the same pdoc.External is displayed in the html text.

I would like to do this for my internal links as well as referring some external resources like
e.g. package.module.functionname where I would like the text to only be functionname and link to an external webpage that I provide like the numpy or scipy documentation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for link inside your project:

```
[visible text](project/my_module.html)
```

or for website

```
[visible text](www.qwant.com)
```